# Drupal-7 - Mailing concent to a list/group of email addresses

Tags: drupal-7

What kind of module should I use to send content to a list of emails:

1. I need to create a groups with list of emails.
2. I need to send it to one or a few of these groups.
3. I need for admins to be able to look at the email addresses which will receive the emails.

I am thinking about using mailchimp, but it does not fulfill all of my needs. Also simplenews_roles can be a good decision, but whre is no version on drupal-7. Is there another option available?

Comment: Please help me somebody. I really need it

Comment: Read description here http://drupal.org/project/mass_messaging